# Proving theorem 7..11 from Rudin's PMA

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Theorem: Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real valued functions defined on metric space $E$. Suppose that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $E$ to the limit function $f$. Let $x$ be a limit point of $E$. Suppose that $ \lim_{t\to x}f_n(t)=:A_n$ exists for every $n\in \mathbb N$.

Then $\lim A_n$ exists and  $\lim_nA_n= \lim_{t\to x} f(t)$

Proof: Let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given. By Cauchy criterion of uniform convergence, there exists $N$ such that $m\ge N, n\ge N\implies |f_m(t)-f_n(t)|\lt\epsilon$ for all $t\in E$. Taking limit $t\to x$ on both sides to get: $|A_m-A_n|\le\epsilon$. It follows that $(A_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence must converge.
To show that $(A_n)$ converges to $\lim_{t\to x} f(t)$, let's note that
since $(f_n)$ converges to $f$ uniformly on $E$, it follows that there exists $N'$ such that $$n\ge N'\implies |f_n(t)-f(t)|<\epsilon\:\: \forall t\in E\tag 1$$

It follows by $(1)$ that $\lim_{t\to x}|f_n(t)-f(t)|\le\epsilon\implies |A_n-\lim_{t\to x}f(t)|\le\epsilon$, whence it follows that $\lim_n A_n=\lim_{t\to x}f(t)$.

Is my proof correct? Thanks.

Comment: By the way: I am not sure this is exercise 7.11 by Rudin. Are you sure about the enumeration?

Comment: @SonGohan: this is **theorem** number 7.11.

Comment: I see, so you are looking for a kinda different proof... makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The major gap in the proof is your failure to justify why $\lim\limits_{t\to x} f(t)$ even exists.

Comment: I see the point. Thank you also for me! So the easiest way is to exploit uniform convergence and convergences you proved for the $(A_n)$ splitting into $$|f(t)-A| \leq\left|f(t)-f_{n}(t)\right|+\left|f_{n}(t)-A_{n}\right|+\left|A_{n}-A\right|$$ as Rudin does.